# Concatenate with SELECT *

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I want to concatenate columns with a `SELECT *`. For example:

`SELECT * FROM Table1`

```
Result:

Col1 Col2
---- ----
Joe  Smith
```

I want to do something like `SELECT CONCAT(*) FROM Table1`

The reason I can't mention the columns by name is that they are being produced by a PIVOT from rows, so there could be any number these columns.

If anyone knows the answer, or knows how to Get the data from any number of rows into a single cell, separated by a comma, please let me know.

Comment: Not really clear what your desired results are here but http://stackoverflow.com/a/32549568/73226

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CONCAT` function requires passing column names explicitly and there is no such thing as `CONCAT(*)`.

On the other hand, `PIVOT` requires an explicit definition of the columns you are pivoting: if you are doing it dynamically, you probably have a variable that holds the names of the columns you are pivoting on and you could use the same variable in dynamic SQL with the `CONCAT` function.